# Etcher alternative for dvd burning

Tags: iso, burning, etcher

Etcher used to be great for burning ISO to USB or microSD card. However, it still doesn't support DVDs. What is the alternative to make a bootable DVD from ISO?

P.S tried a few suggestions and [this one](https://www.passmoz.com/burn-iso-file-to-cd-dvd.html) worked for me.

Comment: Command line is worth exploring: http://www.andrews-corner.org/linux/burning.html#distro

Answer (score 1):

I am using XFBurn (Highly Recommended!)

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install xfburn
```

[image: XFBurn]